# Floating point exception on C, can't solve

Tags: c, compiler-errors, floating-point, strcmp

I wrote a very simple code and when I compiled (Which I told it that when I enter END whatever case it should break that program.) but there is message show up "Floating point exception: 8", I never saw this message before and I have been searching Google which told me that I have something going on with float value that allow program to do something that it shouldn't.

```
/* Program: Taxi Day    
 *
 * Description: Calculate fartest taxi distance.
 *
 * Creator: Thunpisit Amnuaikiatloet #57070503418
 *
 * Create on: November. 26, 2014   17.55.00
 *
 * Lastest modify on: November. 26, 2014   17.55.00
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
char buffer[128];
char END[8] = ("END");
char MAXNAME[128];
int MAXRANGE = 0;
char taxiNumber[32];
int taxiStart = 0;
int taxiEnd = 0;
int taxiTotal = 0;
int taxiCount = 0;

while(1)
{
    /* Ask user to enter Taxi Number */
    printf("\nENTER TAXI NUMBER: ");
    fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
    sscanf(buffer,"%s",taxiNumber);

    /* If Taxi Number entered is END, stop asking */
    if(strcasecmp(taxiNumber,END) == 0)
    {
        break;
    }

    /* Check Taxi Number validate */
    while(strlen(taxiNumber) > 10)
    {
        printf("ENTER TAXI NUMBER: ");
        fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
        sscanf(buffer,"%s",taxiNumber);
    }

    /* Ask user to enter start km */
    printf("ENTER START KM?: ");
    fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
    sscanf(buffer,"%d",&taxiStart);

    /* Check Taxi Start validate */
    while(taxiStart < 0)
    {
        printf("ENTER START KM?: ");
        fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
        sscanf(buffer,"%d",&taxiStart);
    }

    /* Ask user to enter end km */
    printf("ENTER END KM?: ");
    fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
    sscanf(buffer,"%d",&taxiEnd);

    /* Check Taxi Start validate */
    while(taxiStart > taxiEnd)
    {
        printf("ENTER END KM?: ");
        fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
        sscanf(buffer,"%d",&taxiEnd);
    }

    /* Calculate total distance for each taxi */
    taxiTotal = taxiEnd - taxiStart;
    printf("----------------------------------");

    /* Show taxi entered information */
    printf("\nTAXI %s HAS TRAVELED %d KM\n",taxiNumber,taxiTotal);

    /* Compute the taxi that have largest distance */
    if(MAXRANGE < taxiTotal)
    {
        MAXRANGE = taxiTotal;
        strcpy(MAXNAME,taxiNumber);
    }

    /* Count number of taxi entered */
    taxiCount++;
}

/* Print Summary */
printf("\nTAXI %s DROVE THE LONGEST RANGE, WHICH IS %d KM",MAXNAME,MAXRANGE);
printf("THERE ARE %d TAXIS TODAY, AVERAGE RANGE ARE %d KM",taxiCount,taxiTotal/taxiCount);
}
```

Comment: When does the error occur? Looking at your program, if you enter "END" without entering any data, then `taxiCount` will be zero (`0`) and `taxiTotal/taxiCount` will be undefined, which will usually yield a floating point exception error message.

Comment: all the fgets and sscanf calls need to have their returned value checked to assure that the conversion(s) and input(s) were performed successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This likely happens because `taxiTotal/taxiCount` performs a division by zero - which results in an error (manifested as a floating point exception, even if you're just using integers).

That means `taxiCount` is 0, so you should probably rather do

```
if (taxiCount > 0) {
    printf("THERE ARE %d TAXIS TODAY, AVERAGE RANGE ARE %d KM",taxiCount,taxiTotal/taxiCount);
} else {
    puts("THERE ARE NO TAXIS TODAY");
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much! I got it so I need to declare it 1 and then -1 when I use it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell your program gives that exception when the first input is END. Basicly, you did not enter any values at all.

At almost the last line:

```
printf("THERE ARE %d TAXIS TODAY, AVERAGE RANGE ARE %d KM",taxiCount,taxiTotal/taxiCount);
```

You are dividing the value taxiTotal by taxiCount. If no values are entered you are dividing by 0, which is not allowed. Add an IF statement to check that taxicount is not zero before dividing by it.